# Possible to access the internal representation of a neural network trained in Azure Machine Learning Service or Azure Machine Learning Studio?

Tags: neural-network, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm working with data scientists who would like to gain insight and understanding of the neural network models that they train using the visual interfaces in Azure Machine Learning Studio/Service. Is it possible to dump out and inspect the internal representation of a neural network model? Is there a way that I could write code that accesses the nodes and weights of a trained neural network in order to visualize the network as a graph structure? Or if Azure Machine Learning Studio/Service doesn't support this I'd appreciate advice on a different machine learning framework that might be more appropriate for this kind of analysis.

Things I have tried:

- Train Model outputs an ILearnerDotNet (AML Studio) or Model (AML Service). I looked for items to drag into the workspace where I could write custom code such as Execute Python Script. They seem to accept datasets, but not ILearnerDotNet/Model as input.
- I wasn't able to locate documentation about the ILearnerDotNet/Model interfaces.
- Selecting the Train Model output offers the option to Save as Trained Model. This creates a trained model object and that would help me reference the trained model in other places, but I didn't find a way to use this to get at its internals.

I'm new to the Azure Machine Learning landscape, and could use some help with how to get started on how to access this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from Azure ML Exam reference:

> By default, the architecture of neural networks is limited to a single
>   hidden layer with sigmoid as the activation function and softmax in
>   the last layer. You can change this in the properties of the model,
>   opening the Hidden layer specification dropdown list, and selecting a
>   Custom definition script. A text box will appear in which you will be
>   able to insert a Net# script. This script language allows you to
>   define neural networks architectures.

For instance, if you want to create a two layer network, you may put the following code.

```
input Picture [28, 28];
hidden H1 [200] from Picture all;
hidden H2 [200] from H1 all;
output Result [10] softmax from H2 all;
```

Nevertheless, with Net# you will face certain limitations as, it does not accept regularization (neither L2 nor dropout). Also, there is no ReLU activation that are
commonly used in deep learning due to their benefits in backpropagation. You cannot modify the batch size of the Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD). Besides that, you cannot use other optimization algorithms. You can use SGD with momentum, but not others like Adam, or RMSprop. You cannot define recurrent or recursive neural networks.

Another great tool is CNTK (Cognitive Toolkit) that allows you defining your computational graph and create a fully customizable model.
Quote from documentation

> It is a Microsoft open source deep learning toolkit. Like other deep
>   learning tools, CNTK is based on the construction of computational
>   graphs and their optimization using automatic differentiation. The
>   toolkit is highly optimized and scales efficiently (from CPU, to GPU,
>   to multiple machines). CNTK is also very portable and flexible; you
>   can use it with programming languages like Python, C#, or C++, but you
>   can also use a model description language called BrainScript.

Comment: Thanks! This is great information about how I could define the structure of the neural network for Azure ML. However, it doesn't answer the question of whether it is possible to access the internal information from the trained model such as the learned weights. Taking a look at CNTK sounds like good advice.

Comment: As far as I understand it is impossible to visualize the trained model in AML Studio. So the answer is using CNTK